# can anyone help me with my code in c# it always outputs 0 in message box

Tags: c#

thanks for your fast response guys, so this is what I have now..

my problem is, it requires me to add parameter in Form2 f2 = new Form2(); part but if i did i got this error Error  "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property "

for my Form1 I didnt edit this one ^

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        int userInputValue;
        string userInputValueConverted;
        string formulaShow = "";
        public double answer = 0.0;
        public double output;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




            f2.DuAnswer = output;
            f2.Formula.Text = formulaShow;
            f2.Show();
```

for my FORM2 i only have 1 constructor

```
public double duAnswer;

public Form2(double output)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    duAnswer = output;
}



public double DuAnswer
{
    get
    {
        return duAnswer;
    }

    set
    {
        duAnswer = value;
    }
}
```

and for my result button

```
 private void result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + duAnswer.ToString("F2"));
        }
```

Comment: Please, paste only code which describes your problem

Comment: What does your debugger show you?

Comment: no error, it just give me 0 value

Comment: I cleaned up your question, Lazyberezosky had a good point. Try to paste the code that narrow your problem. Anyways, I'm pretty sure Reed Cospey found your problem, so if he really did don't forget to mark is answer as Accepted. Also, I suggest you have a look to our Help section : http://stackoverflow.com/help if you haven't already did :)

Comment: thanks^ and sorry keep that in mind >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you show your `Form2` instance, you're creating a *new instance of Form2*.  This isn't needed, but instead, you need to set the answer on the existing form2:

```
// Don't create this
// Form2 outP = new Form2(output);

f2.DuAnswer = output;
f2.Formula.Text = formulaShow;
f2.Show();
```

This also means you don't need the second constructor:

```
// public Form2(double output)
// {
//    duAnswer = output;
// }
```

Also note that, if you do decide to include the second alternative constructor, it's important that it also calls `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public Form2(double output)
{
   InitializeComponent(); // This is critical for a form
   duAnswer = output;
}
```

You can alternatively use [constructor chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx) to accomplish this:

```
public Form2(double output)
   : this()
{
   duAnswer = output;
}
```

Comment: so how can I call form2 without creating new instance?

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje You've already created an instance: `Form2 f2 = new Form2();`  You're *reusing* the instance you created already (`f2`), instead of making a second instance.

Comment: thanks for this, but I have a new problem, i follow your instruction, I set f2.Formula.Text = formulaShow; and i only have this at the top Form2 f2 = new Form2();, however i got error A field initializer cannot reference...

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje I'm saying to put this in your `submit_Click` method - just comment out the line where you create the new form, and add my code, and it should work.  Don't try to put this at the top of your class...

Comment: I just did what you told me but my debugger requires me to add parameter in  Form2 f2 = new Form2(); can you check my edited code post?

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje The code I wrote above needs to be inside of a method.  In your original code, it was in the `submit_Click` method - I would leave it there.  You ca'nt just add it inside of the form itself...

Comment: ok, I already create a method and call it in submit_Clicl, but still the error is in my Form2 f2 = new Form2(); do i need to put output as a parameter?

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje Basically, if you use *your original code*, all you have to do is change the one section I listed above, and nothing else,a nd it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the value of answer to the output, but instantiating Form2 with the output variable that does not have any value assigned to it.

Why do you need two of them anyway? Why not just do Form2 frm = new Form2(answer);

Comment: it gives me an error if only instantiate 1 form, it says A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field...........

Comment: Like Reed said, you don't really need to instantiate the form again. Just change duAnswer of Form2 to public, assign the answer variable to this public var and in the end do f2.Show() (or .ShowDialog())